# jquerymobile: navigation is not working with jquery.mobile-1.0a2

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have just started looking into jquerymobile, done simple samples using `jquery.mobile-1.0a1`.

I have home.html, auboutus.html pages. In home page, i have a listview with a external link to aboutus.html. It is working fine, by clicking on about us link, about us page is loading with head navigation bar with "Back" button.

Now by using `jquery.mobile-1.0a2`, in about us page, the header navigation bar got disappeared.

Here is my sample code:

## home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="banner">
        <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="aboutus.html" >About Us</a>
    </li></ul>
</div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

## aboutus.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="banner">
        <h2>About Us</h2>
    </div>
<p>about us about us about us about us </p>
</div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alpha 1? I would suggest updating the the newly release beta 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should think about using the page design JQuery mobile prefers. You can find it here, you dont need to define different .html files, you can simple add multiple 'pages' with different id's to one html file. The refering is then simple. Check out this link: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html#../../docs/pages/docs-pages.html

For your link if you want to refer to external, try this: `<a href="multipage.html" rel="external">Link</a>`

Comment: Hi @zyrex, rel="external" is working for me, but i'm not getting automatic "Back" button on header toolbar of aboutus.html

Comment: Check this link and search for the back button .. its written how to add it. http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html and dont forget to accept my answer as correct or as useful if it helped you. thanks

Comment: thank you @zyrex, I'm able to define "Back" button on header tool bar. But the smooth transition is missing in the navigation..

Comment: Check the document page for "Pages & Dialogs" and then for "Page transitions" ... the transition which you call smooth is dependent on the way you create the button. is you ref external, its gone. Check the documentation, its very good.